# Unresolved function or method done(), spring with react

Tags: spring, reactjs

Im currently following this https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/ tutorial. But when I write my app.js I get "Unresolved function or method done().

I have tried the other suggestion cleaning cache and add Node.js as global. 
What am I missing?

```
const client = require('./client');

componentDidMount() {
            client({method: 'GET', path: '/api/employees'}).done(response => {
                this.setState({coaches: response.entity._embedded.employees});
            });
        }
```

**Client file **

```
'use strict';

var rest = require('rest');
var defaultRequest = require('rest/interceptor/defaultRequest');
var mime = require('rest/interceptor/mime');
var uriTemplateInterceptor = require('./api/uriTemplateInterceptor');
var errorCode = require('rest/interceptor/errorCode');
var baseRegistry = require('rest/mime/registry');

var registry = baseRegistry.child();

registry.register('text/uri-list', require('./api/uriListConverter'));
registry.register('application/hal+json', require('rest/mime/type/application/hal'));

module.exports = rest
    .wrap(mime, {registry: registry})
    .wrap(uriTemplateInterceptor)
    .wrap(errorCode)
    .wrap(defaultRequest, {headers: {'Accept': 'application/hal+json'}});
```

[image]

Comment: show the definition for `client` - your error is saying that `client.done` is not defined

Comment: @FuzzyTree updated my question

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do this tutorial following the tutor's code. The main trouble is that it is not actual or the author doesn't upgrade it because of his own motives. Anyway, if you look at the `package.json` you will the version of react in dependecies. So just change the react version

```
    "react": "^15.3.2",
"react-dom": "^15.3.2"
```

[github. Package.json](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-react-and-spring-data-rest/blob/master/basic/package.json)